# use UIAppearance methods for customizing UIAlertView

Tags: iphone, ios, customization, uialertview, uiappearance

I know that `UIAlertView` conforms to `UIAppearance` and `UIAppearanceContainer`.

But how do I use `UIAppearance` to customize/style `UIAlertView`? I am not able to find it over the net.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can't use `UIAppearance` to customise `UIAlertView`.

`UIAlertView` only shows as having `UIAppearance` because `UIView` conforms to `UIAppearance` and `UIAlertView` is a subclass of `UIView`.

It doesn't actually implement it though.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `UIAlertView` functionality, modally view, etc... you can subclass it.

Here an example:
http://www.albertopasca.it/whiletrue/2012/07/objective-c-modal-view-navigation-tabbar-controller-projects/

hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to customize UIAlertView, i made subclass of UIAlertView, you can find it on github [WCAlertView](https://github.com/m1entus/WCAlertView) which support similiar proxy to UIAppearance. You can use it to set default appearce for all WCAlertView:

```
[WCAlertView setDefaultCustomiaztonBlock:^(WCAlertView *alertView) {
        alertView.labelTextColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.11f green:0.08f blue:0.39f alpha:1.00f];
        alertView.labelShadowColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

        UIColor *topGradient = [UIColor colorWithRed:1.0f green:1.0f blue:1.0f alpha:1.0f];
        UIColor *middleGradient = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.93f green:0.94f blue:0.96f alpha:1.0f];
        UIColor *bottomGradient = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.89f green:0.89f blue:0.92f alpha:1.00f];
        alertView.gradientColors = @[topGradient,middleGradient,bottomGradient];

        alertView.outerFrameColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:250.0f/255.0f green:250.0f/255.0f blue:250.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f];

        alertView.buttonTextColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.11f green:0.08f blue:0.39f alpha:1.00f];
        alertView.buttonShadowColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
}];
```

Comment: Did you use this in apps that are in the AppStore? The documentation clearly states that UIAlertView should not be subclassed and is intended to use as-is: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIAlertView_Class/UIAlertView/UIAlertView.html